# Select multiple records in two tables with same ID?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `module_attributes` and `module_attribute_details`. The details are subs of the attributes. Not every attribute has subs.

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a single query that can select multiple attribute records with different detail-records.

An example here:

```
SELECT a.attribute_id
     , a.description
     , a.extra_cost
     , d.description option_description
     , d.extra_cost option_extra_cost 
  FROM module_attributes a
  LEFT 
  JOIN module_attribute_details d
    ON d.f_attribute_id = a.attribute_id 
   AND d.attribute_detail_id IN (30,null,29,null)
 WHERE a.attribute_id IN (27,28,27,29);
```

The returned result is (ofcourse) only 3 records, because `attribute_id` 27 is called twice.

I want to return all 4 records with different `details`, is this possible in one query?

Comment: try `group by details`

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: Theoretically you could make four queries with UNION ALL to get also duplicates, but I'd rather handle it in the system using this query rather than try to force the DB into giving out duplicates

Comment: GROUP BY `module_attribute_details`? How?

Comment: yes @Abayob try it

Comment: `AS \`option.description\`` - Isn't that going to be a bit confusing? But, aside from that, I think you're confusing issues of data storage and retrieval with those of data display. The latter is best handled in application level code. UNLESS, you're actually after records (30,29),(null,28),(29,27), and (null,29)!!